# Ansible: Change SSH key

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keys

I have an inventory of multiple servers. SSH access to these servers is secured using PEM key files. I would like to periodically change the PEM key used by my servers. So, I would like to use Ansible to do the following:

1. Generate a new PEM key file
2. For each server in my inventory, connect to the server using old PEM key file
3. Install new PEM key file
4. Test to ensure SSH with new key works and old key *does not* work

What is the best way to do this via Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split this in three playbooks.

The first to generate a new PEM key. This will run locally. See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks

The second one will do the rollout. So it copies the key to all servers. You can use [authorized_key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) or [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) depending on what your preferred workflow is. But thats another question.

The third step then would be a testing playbook, maybe with an assert statement or just using ping to ensure the connection works.

When you have all this playbooks combine them in a single with include or add this three plays in one playbook in the right order. See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html

Comment: Thanks. This looks great! I will try it out.